# Transferring data from one application to another using implicit intent

Tags: android-intent, implicit

I have an app - App 1 and App 2. I am calling App 2 from App 1 using implicit intent.
PFB the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                intent.setAction("com.sharing.action.CALLING");
```

called from App 1.

Next is any input from App 1 should be fetched in App 2 without using any shared preference.
Simply, i should be able to do this using implicit intent attributes.

Is it possible? If so , how to do as when i give this part of code :-

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setData(Uri.parse(name))
```

My App 1 crashes after this bit of code.
Also in App 2 intent filter  what I should mention ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. Use putExtra in App 1 and getStringExtra in App 2.
That is the best solution for sharind data using Implicit intent.